# Pass Eventbrite attendee parameters to custom order confirmation page via redirect URL

Tags: eventbrite

Is there a way to provide parameters to the redirect URL in the Eventbrite order confirmation workflow?

I'd like to forward the attendee ID / order ID (or comma-separated IDs) to my custom page as parameters, so I could perform a lookup and display customized information relevant to that attendee. With a static redirect URL, everyone sees the same 'order confirmation page', with no personalization.

What I'm trying to do is generate an itinerary for each attendee. When they purchase their ticket, they are asked a bunch of questions that determine what their itinerary will look like. Once they complete their order, I'd like to send them to their personalized itinerary page (e.g. `http://custom.com/.../<attendee_id>`), which they can then bookmark on their mobile device.

If this isn't possible, the only other option I have is to redirect them to a page where they have to manually key in their order number, or barcode number. Not the most elegant option, for several reasons.

Please advise!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you include "$event_id" or "$order_id" anywhere in your order confirmation URL, then those values will automatically get swapped in for you.

Comment: Thanks! Consider adding this to documentation - I'm sure other developers will find it useful! Relevant docs: http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/portal/articles/426236-order-confirmation-customization#redirect and http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/workflows/#orders

Comment: I just had the same problem, so thank you guys! I really wonder why none of this in the documentation. Do you guys know what other parameters can be passed?