# Can I pass additional values in the order confirmation redirect URL?

Tags: eventbrite

Thanks to user ʀɣαɳĵ for his answer to [a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868008/pass-eventbrite-attendee-parameters-to-custom-order-confirmation-page-via-redire).

Apparently, when directing people to a website using the confirmation page redirect, I can pass in eventbrite specific information in the form of "$event_id" or "$order_id"

This alone is great - thanks Eventbrite for this level of integration. I'm going to be cheeky and ask for a bit more! What would be great, in addition to the order id and event id, would be to pass in additional things, such as the order value, as that way I can start to do interesting ecommerce things with Google Analytics, Adwords, and other Website Tracking.

What I'd like are things like $order_amount and $coupon_code and $discount_percent and $discount_amount

Are there additional values like this?

I know I can figure out these things manually based on the order ID alone, but that A) takes time, B) prevents me from doing anything automatic on the page based on their order amount, and C) prevents me from integrating with various web analytics.

And, if this doesn't exist already, could we put it into the next version?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Has some found out relevant information about that?