# Find out if user purchased ticket - Eventbrite API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventbrite, ticket-system

I am using the eventbrite API through the [eventbrite client gem](https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite-client.rb) to generate concerts from my site.

On my concerts#show page I embed the ticket widget for users to buy tickets. From there, users will be led to eventbrite.com's concert page to complete the purchase. Then they get redirected to a return url on my site that I can define.

The question is: How do I know if someone bought a ticket? Or am I just blind and cannot find it in the [documentation](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/#methods)?

Comment: does [user_list_tickets](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_tickets/) or [event_list_attendees](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/) not cover this?

Comment: @RyanMacG I wouldn't know how. I could list all the event's tickets, but how would I know one of them belongs to the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have a specific event, you can use the [event_list_attendees](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/) API to get all of the currently registered attendees.

What may work better is referenced here:

[Pass Eventbrite attendee parameters to custom order confirmation page via redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868008/pass-eventbrite-attendee-parameters-to-custom-order-confirmation-page-via-redire)

When the order completes and the user is redirected, you can digest $event_id and $order_id to perform some action.  All you'd need to do is put those in your redirect_url and then write your own logic to process those on your end.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! What other parameters can I pass in there? I really wonder why none of this in the documentation...