# Eventbrite Email Variables

Tags: email, variables, eventbrite

Target: Send customized/personalized email msg to eventbrite attendee including custom links with event/order details as parameters in querystring & description.

### Example:

Hello Dear $attendee,
Your ticket reservation for $event_title (ID: $event_id) has been approved and your order ID is: $order_id

I've already read the following topic but it didn't help, I'm asking for another thing -Email Attendees" not "Order Confirmation".
[Pass Eventbrite attendee parameters to custom order confirmation page via redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868008/pass-eventbrite-attendee-parameters-to-custom-order-confirmation-page-via-redire)

Anyway to achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official answer received from "Eventbrite Customer Support" as follow (request id: 619986):

> Thanks for reaching out!
>
> For emailing attendees via our official "Emails to Attendees" feature,
>   there is no way to personalize it to each attendee without sending
>   individual emails and calling out the specific attendee. If you are
>   sending a bulk email to multiple attendees there won't be a way to
>   include any personal messaging to individual attendees.
>
> I hope this info helps, and please don't hesitate to reach out if you
>   have any additional questions! If you have any developer-specific
>   questions you may want to reach out to our developer team at
>   api@eventbrite.com.

Comment: You may use Pygmento service to send custom emails to each attendee using any variable from Eventbrite : https://www.pygmento.com/en/blog/eventbrite-custom-tickets-pdf/.

Answer (score 2):

I work on the product team for Eventbrite.

Unfortunately, dynamic fields aren't something that we've built for the email confirmation. I'll make sure this gets added to our feature request queue.

Here is some more information on what the order confirmation email looks like: http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/portal/articles/426236-order-confirmation-customization

As you can see, Eventbrite automatically sends out an email with the event title and order number. On this order confirmation email, we allow for custom text to be added -- but we don't allow for massive customization. This is done by design as we found that with too much customization, the format was being broken and attendees weren't able to accurately decipher the important information from the confirmation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great, but you may add it as advanced features for advanced users & restrict it with whatever you want. We'll be looking for these awesome features for your awesome service. Keep Moving Forward (y)

Comment: I would love to have attendee given name and surname variables!

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested by Pygmento custom emails & tickets : https://www.pygmento.com/en/blog/eventbrite-custom-tickets-pdf/.

You can use the service to send an email to each attendee using any variable from Eventbrite : given name, surname, ticket class, barcode, or even the user-defined checkout fields.

PDF ticket customization is also possible.